# Exchange Server 2013: how to sendas <shared mailbox> via SMTP?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, exchange-2013, shared-mailbox

I have a 3rd party program (namely a sales / invoicing program) which has the ability to send emails from within the program, for the purpose of sending invoices to clients / customers.

Within this program I have a configuration window for configuring an SMTP server with the following fields:

Server:
Port:
Username:
Password:

Is there anyway to configure this to SendAs a shared mailbox email?  In other words, I have a shared mailbox which is `accounting@mydomain.com` for which the user `sarah.smith@mydomain.com` has SendAs and Full Access permissions.  I want the outgoing emails with invoices to use the `accounting@mydomain.com` email address.

I think the answer is no.  I think I need a separate field for "E-mail address" and then I could put the e-mail as `accounting@mydomain.com` and the username as `sarah.smith@mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With exchange, if someone has SendAs and FullAccess, you *should* be able to use username/sharedboxname (i.e. john.smith/ar) as the user to allow sending as that name.

Comment: Interesting.  I will try it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this worked, but it didn't *not* work, and the way my program interacts with Outlook is different than I first thought.  In conclusion, I will accept this answer as the best for now.